# cx_freeze matplotlib error

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, cx-freeze

I have been trying to convert a wxpython program to an exe with cx_freeze.  The program works as expected before using cx_freeze.  Once I freeze if I click on a panel that has a matplotlib graph embedding the app closes.  If I get rid of all the matplotlib code the exe runs as expected.  I have been searching on line for days to find the answer with no success so any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

setup.py

```
import os
import sys
import cx_Freeze
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = 'C:\xxxx\\xxxx\\DLLs\\tcl86t.dll'
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = 'C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\DLLs\\tk86t.dll'


Mydata_files = [('C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\', 'pics'),
                ('C:\\xxxx\\xxxx\\', 'models')]

path = []

includes = ["scipy", "scipy.integrate" ,"scipy.sparse", "scipy.spatial.ckdtree",
            "scipy.sparse.csgraph._validation", 'sklearn', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg',
            'matplotlib.figure', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib', 'numpy', 
            'pandas', 'numpy.lib.format']

packages = ['matplotlib', 'wx.lib.pubsub', 'wx.lib.agw', 'pandas', 'numpy', 
            'scipy.stats','scipy', 'sklearn', 'matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg',
            'matplotlib.figure', 'matplotlib.backends', 'matplotlib', 
            'numpy.lib.format']

excludes = []

base = None

if sys.platform =='win32':
    base = 'Win32GUI'

GUI2Exe_Target_1 = Executable(
    # what to build
    script = "main.py",
    initScript = None,
    base = base,
    targetName = "test.exe"
    )

setup(

    version = "0.0.1",
    description = "test",
    author = "X",
    name = "test",

    options = {"build_exe": {"includes": includes,
                             "excludes": excludes,
                             "packages": packages,
                             "include_files": Mydata_files,
                             "path": path
                             }
               },

    executables = [GUI2Exe_Target_1]
    )
```

the matplotlib imports in the .py script:

```
import os
import sys
import wx
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from wx.lib.pubsub import pub
```

[image]

Comment: did you try to execute from the command shell, to capture the exception producing the crash ?

Comment: When I run it from command line no error spits out the application just closes.

Comment: Hmmm, no clue. You should try to eliminate as much code as possible from your current script to build an example with the minimal lines of code reproducing the error. It is possible you get the clue when doing that exercise or at least you can post it for others to test

Comment: Thank you for your time, when I run the code taking out the matplotlib graphs it runs exactly as expected, so I figured maybe someone knew I was missing a certain DLL.  If I manually move the matplotlib folder into the build file I receive the traceback error that I attached the photos of it that helps at all.

Comment: Did you ever make progress on this?  I am encountering a similar issue!  All the best, thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I was never able to figure it out, and since it was a side project I just never turned it into an .exe. I just run it from thr command on the one computer. Good luck!